# Tailwind CSS checkbox styles are not working

Tags: html, checkbox, next.js, jsx, tailwind-css

I have a checkbox in my Next.js project and after adding some Tailwind utility classes nothing takes effect except changes to width, height and cursor. Color, bg, border, etc. don't work.

```
        <div className="flex py-4 m-auto w-2/3 justify-between items-start">
          <div className="w-1/7">
            <div className="border-b pb-4">
              <h1 className="mb-2 font-medium">Filter 1</h1>
              <label htmlFor="c1">
                <div className="flex group active:ring-2 ring-black rounded">
                  <input
                    id="c1"
                    type="checkbox"
                    className="rounded-full h-8 w-8 cursor-pointer bg-red-100 border-red-300 text-red-600 focus:ring-red-200"
                  />
                  <p className="pl-2 text-reg cursor-pointer group-hover:underline decoration-solid">
                    Subfilter 1
                  </p>
                </div>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

`cursor-pointer`, `h-8` and `w-8` are the only utility classes that are working in the checkbox. `color` still defaults to blue, there's no ring appearing on focus, and `bg` still white.

Others elements in the example code like `p`, `div` and `h1` are working perfectly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add `tailwindcss/forms` to your `config` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      // ...
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/forms")],
};
```

You can read more about it in the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#forms) and the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-forms).

[Here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/ydsiXRwRfJ) is a working example in Tailwind Play.

Comment: thank you very much! I'm new with Tailwind and I didn't know that I needed to install forms to style some basic html elements, hope this doesn't change others styles in my application but al least the checkboxes are customizable now

Comment: Happy it worked for you :) You can view all the form elements that are added with the plugin: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-forms#basic-usage

Answer (score 5):

The key here is [appearance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance) CSS property - set it to `none` to kinda reset default browser styling

> The appearance CSS property is used to control native appearance of UI controls, that are based on operating system's theme

In Tailwind it is `appearance-none` [utility](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/appearance)

> Use appearance-none to reset any browser specific styling on an element.

```html
<input
  type="checkbox"
  class="appearance-none ..."
/>
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/ZKHyPs7Uwr)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution, it can be very useful and I didn't even know about it. I'm still giving a chance to tailwind forms in order to use some of its utilities but this simple solution that doesn't affect the rest of the code is something that I will definitely take into account.